# Browser failed to load resource with deep levels of folders

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser, static-resource

I have encountered a strange problem.

Here is the screenshot from the inspector tools.
[image]

The browser failed to load some resources even though the resources do exist. When I open the URL from another tab, the resource is successfully loaded.

URL in image:

- `http://angular.local/app/js/controllers/advertise/cm_code/list.js`
- `http://angular.local/app/js/controllers/advertise/create_new_shop/create_new_shop.js`
- `http://angular.local/app/js/controllers/advertise/media_settings/media_settings.js`
- `http://angular.local/app/js/controllers/advertise/register_cm_code/register_cm_code.js`

Other resources with fewer levels of folders are loadable. Ex:

- `http://angular.local/app/js/controllers/admin/change_password.js`

I thought the problem is from my web server, but the problem still remained after switching between NodeJS and Apache.

Has anybody encounter similar problems and got any solutions?

Comment: Do you have a anti virus plugin? I once had a similar problem when my anti virus was blocking some resources.

Comment: Try removing the underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change file location to outter level of folders.

The other way to load many files is using preload.js. You should try this.